# Unable to import database in Vertica Management Console

Tags: vertica

I have problem with importing database in Vertica Management console 7.2.3.

Whenever I try to connect to database it complains about password:

```
{"message":"Could not connect to the database. Invalid Password","status":"invalidPwd"}
```

That is the same password and user dbadmin which I use to connect to the same database via admintools. It works in admintools.

In the agent.log I could only find following:

```
INFO:wsgi:10.14.44.102 - - [26/Apr/2017:14:04:09 +0000] "POST /databases/dwh_vertica/users/null HTTP/1.1" 401 167 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.7.0_80)"
INFO:wsgi:10.14.44.102 - - [26/Apr/2017:14:06:16 +0000] "POST /databases/dwh_vertica/users/null HTTP/1.1" 401 167 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5 (Java/1.7.0_80)"
```

Could you please do let me know why I can't connect?

Comment: "users/null" looks suspicious.  Are you sure that MC knows to use dbadmin?

Comment: yes, I fill user with "dbadmin" in connection to database field